# Can't reinstall the Camera icon on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera

My daughter accidentally deleted the Camera icon from my iPhone 4. I have since reinstalled everything, updated to IOS 5 and have sync'd the phone via iTunes etc. But I still can't see it and can't find a way of adding it to as an app, if that's what I need to do.

How to get the Camera icon back?

Comment: Can you go to the camera by sliding up from the bottom of lock screen?

Answer (score 6):

You actually can't remove the Camera app, but you can move it. Perhaps it is hidden in a group.

- Go to Settings -> General -> Reset and tap "Reset Home Screen Layout".

"Camera" should reappear in the first page, but if it doesn't its likely a parental control or a profile restricting camera use.

- Go to Settings -> General -> profiles and delete all of the ones you don't need. Inspect the ones you wish to keep to see if one restricts the camera.

If that still doesn't work, you'll want to back the device up and restore it to get if a hardware or software problem is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When this happened to me I followed the following instructions; go to `Settings > General > Restrictions`. Then toggle the Camera `Off` then `On` again.

Exit, then the Camera icon should be back.

Comment: What iOS version was this? Did you have Restrictions enabled already?

Comment: iOS 6.1.4   restriction was ON

Comment: As of iOS 13, the Restrictions feature has been moved, go to Settings > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Allowed Apps to disable/enable the Camera App

Answer (score 2):

As it's not possible to remove stock apps, you should be able to find Camera by using the `Search iPhone` feature. (Press `Home button` or `swipe left-to-right` when in the first screen.)

When you type "camera" to the search field, the results should give access to Camera and reveal the folder it possibly is in. If result doesn't list any folder on the right side, then Camera should be in some of the screens.

Answer (score 1):

As David said, it's impossible to delete a stock app such as the Camera app. Your daughter could have done one of two things:

1. Moved the Camera app into a folder somewhere. If this is the case, simply open Settings, go to General, scroll down to Reset, and tap "Reset Home Screen Layout".
2. This is less likely, but it is possible that she created a restriction for the Camera. In this case, you will have to get the restriction passcode that she (accidentally) set. Once you have this, open Settings, go to General, open Restrictions, type in the passcode, and switch Camera back to "On". From there you can also disable any other restrictions she may have set.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to next pages and make sure you have to scroll up to last page because the same thing happened with my camera and I wasted lot of time in finding two pages as I had actually two pages and I didn't realize that the camera has moved to 3rd page.